# Go through all folders whose names contain a given pattern

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

let suppose I have folders with names af32, af42, af, and I want to print the last modification date of all folders whose have af* pattern for example .
I writed shell that will take folder or files as parameter and return modification date for that folder .

```
stat -c %y "$1"
```

this code will return the last modification date to folder .
but how can I apply this code to more than one folder whose have same pattern in their name

Comment: `ll -lt | grep af` you can try this

Comment: You can run for loop. Something, like, for i in `ls af*`; do  stat -c %y; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to search recursively in `search_folder/` for directories (`-type d`) matching a specific pattern glob (e.g. `-name 'af*'`):

```bsh
find search_folder/ -type d -name 'af*' -exec stat -c '%y %n' '{}' \;
```

This will then execute (`-exec ... \;`) the command `stat -c '%y %n' '{}'` on each of the search results, replacing `{}` with the result path, starting with the given `search_folder/`.

Note that I modified your `stat` output to include the file name/path `%n` in the result, because otherwise you wouldn't see what file each modification date belongs to.

Comment: yes thank you for your reply . the code working fine but for one folder. if I have folders with name af1,af2,af3 that code will give me result just for one folder

Comment: You have to replace `search_folder/` with a parent directory that contains all the folders of which you want the info. Then it will recursively search inside that location and run the `stat` command on all matching folders below it.

Comment: More efficient with: `-exec … +`

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell globbing as follows:

```
stat -c %y af*/
```

`af*/` matches every directory in the current directory beginning with “af”.
If this throws an error like

```
bash: /usr/bin/stat: Argument list too long
```

use this `printf` approach instead:

```
printf '%s\0' af*/ | xargs -0 stat -c %y
```

#### Example run

You might want to add `%n` to `stat`’s output…

```
$ ls
af  af32  af42  bf  cg45
$ stat -c %y af*/
2018-06-05 18:59:55.355277977 +0200
2018-06-04 19:01:28.968869600 +0200
2018-06-06 18:58:15.968639269 +0200
$ stat -c '%y %n' af*/
2018-06-05 18:59:55.355277977 +0200 af/
2018-06-04 19:01:28.968869600 +0200 af32/
2018-06-06 18:58:15.968639269 +0200 af42/
```